# Switching between Mac Safari browser windows on French-Canadian Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, safari, windows, shortcut

Use Command + ` to rotate between windows of the same application.

---

How about for those of us with a French-Canadian keyboard?

And is there a way to achieve it on the Trackpad? I know I've done it before by accident, but I don't recall the way to do it.

Comment: Can you help us out a bit so we don’t have to go off-site to research the F/C keyboard layout?  What causes `Cmd +` to be an issue?

Comment: The Cmd + is not an issue.  It's just that the ` sign on a French-Canadian keyboard is achieved via Option + ^

Comment: To type an apostrophe, such as I'm late for dinner, I normally hold the Shift key and tap on the comma key.